# Why is the derivative of the linear transport equation this sum?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, linear-pde

Im approaching PDE theory as a newbie, and there is a super simple question I cannot wrap my head around yet:

Let the PDE *linear transport equation* be defined on $\mathbb{R}^n \times (0,\infty)$ as
$$ u_t + b \cdot \nabla u$$ with $b=(b_1,\ldots, b_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t>0$.

If we define $z(s) := u(x+sb,t+s)$ with $s \in \mathbb{R}$, then why is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial s}z(s) = \nabla u (x+sb,t+s) \cdot b + u_t(x+sb,t+s) \quad ?$$

Why is the derivation of $z$ that way? To be honest, I thought naively that

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial s}z(s) = \frac{\partial}{\partial s} u (x+sb,t+s) = \begin{pmatrix}  \dot{u}(x+sb,t+s) \cdot b  \\ \dot{u}(x+sb,t+s)  \end{pmatrix}  $$ or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First notice that $z(s)$ has values in $\mathbb{R}$, so $\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}$ must be one-dimensional.

The function $u(x+sb, t+s)$ is a composition of $u$ and the mapping $s\mapsto (x+sb,t+s)$. Hence
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial s}u(x+sb, t+s)) = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}u(x+sb,t+s)\cdot b_i + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}u(x+sb,t+s)\cdot 1 $$
$$= \nabla u(x+sb,t+s)\cdot b + u_t(x+sb,t+s).$$

Comment: Thanks, nice shot @Cleopatra ! How come do we have a sum $\sum$ of the derivates? Why does this correspond to $\nabla u$... I thought $\nabla u$ is the gradient of u..

Comment: Yes, $\nabla u$ is the gradient. So $\nabla u\cdot b$ is the scalar product of $\nabla u$ and $b$ and hence it is equal to $\sum \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\cdot b_i$. 
Why we have this sum follows from the chain rule.

Comment: Cheers @Cleopatra, thanks for your enlightment, sorry for my dumbness